# add process names that contains space in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

i have listed all the processes with handle.exe that access one directory.

```
function Get-FileHandle ($HPath){
$handles = handle $HPath 
}
```

the output seems like:

> Nthandle v4.11 - Handle viewer Copyright (C) 1997-2017 Mark
> Russinovich Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)
>
> jabra-direct.exe   pid: 12716  type: File           838:
> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
>
> Creative Cloud.exe pid: 4280   type: File           9D0:
> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
>
> Adobe CEF Helper.exe pid: 12916  type: File           494:
> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
>
> brave.exe          pid: 2920   type: File           690:
> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
>
> brave.exe          pid: 13828  type: File           344:
> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Now I am trying to list only the processnames without all the other values.
tha code i have, is:

```
foreach ($handle in $gethandle) {
$handle.Split(" ") | ?{$_ -like "*exe"}
}
```

The output is:

> jabra-direct.exe
>
> Cloud.exe
>
> Helper.exe
>
> brave.exe
>
> brave.exe

everything fine untill the processname contains a space. It should be creative cloud.exe and not cloud.exe.

How can i make it work ? sothat creative cloud.exe will be shown and not only cloud.exe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet.

```
$handles = handle $HPath    # assuming handle.exe can be found via PATH env var
$selected = $handles | Select-String -Pattern '.*?(?= +pid:)'
$processNames = $selected.Matches.Value    # array of process names
```

The `Select-String` line extracts the process names from the output using a regular expression:

- `.*?` - everything up to the following pattern (as little as possible to trim trailing whitespace)
- `(?=` - starts a positive lookahead pattern

  - `+` - one ore more space characters
  - `pid:` - literal "pid:"
- `)` - ends the positive lookahead pattern

The positive lookahead makes sure that we only find sub strings followed by `" pid:"`, without including `" pid:"` in the result.

The expression `$selected.Matches.Value` is a shortcut for:

```
$processNames = @()
foreach( $sel in $selected ) {
    foreach( $match in $sel.Matches ) {
        $processNames += $match.Value
    }
}
```

When PowerShell can't find a property on an object that is an array, it automatically searches each array member for that property and returns an array of all values that is has found. This is called [member enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1#member-enumeration).

Comment: Thx man... That works. Is there any way to save the PIDs in a separate array and then put them all together next to each others, like: ProcesssName 1 : ProcessID 1, ProcessName 2 : ProcessID 2, and so on ?

Comment: @keeran Either use an extra `Select-String` call or do it with one call by specifying groups in the RegEx like this: `(.*?) +pid: (\d+)`. You can get group values like `$selected.Matches | ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }`. Use group index 2 for PID.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code and adapt if necessary.
Regex is `(.*)(?=pid:)pid:\s(\d+)\stype:\s([^\d]+)\s([\dABCDEF]+):\s(.*)` that combine a positive lookahead and capturing groups. Then just use the auto property `$Matches` to extract capturing group values.

```
$output = @"
Nthandle v4.11 - Handle viewer Copyright (C) 1997-2017 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

jabra-direct.exe pid: 12716 type: File 838: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Creative Cloud.exe pid: 4280 type: File 9D0: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Adobe CEF Helper.exe pid: 12916 type: File 494: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

brave.exe pid: 2920 type: File 690: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

brave.exe pid: 13828 type: File 344: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
"@
$output = $output.Split("`r`n")
$output | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match "(.*)(?=pid:)pid:\s(\d+)\stype:\s([^\d]+)\s([\dABCDEF]+):\s(.*)") {
        $props = [ordered]@{
          Name = $Matches[1]
          PID = $Matches[2]
          Type = $Matches[3]
          Handle = $Matches[4]
          Path = $Matches[5]
        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```